# Stripe Webhook: E_WEBHOOK_REQUEST_ERROR

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, webhooks, adonis.js

I am currently working on Stripe webhooks using Adonis.js. I created a middleware to check if the coming request is from stripe. But it's always returning an error.

here's my code:

```
let signature = request.header('stripe-signature')
let webhookEvent = request.post().type
let signingSecret = Config.get('stripe.whsec.' + webhookEvent.replace(/\./g, '_'))
await Stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.raw(), signature, signingSecret)
await next()
```

I don't know what's wrong but I am sure that the whsec_xxxx that I am passing is correct. Does anyone experienced this?

Comment: most of the error is due to `request.raw()` is not really raw body. 
Do you have any middleware before this webhook handler that might alter the request body?

Comment: no I don't have any. But on the documentation of adonis.js that how they call raw data

Comment: I recognized something weird, when I'm removing the await in next(), it works fine. How was that?

Comment: Try : https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/using-stripe-webhook-problem-with-incoming-request/135